# Jest - Mock document location href with Angular Routing Event

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, routes, navigation

I'm testing with Jest Angular Routing, I need to get the document location href when the Angular routing changes.

```
describe('track Routing Angular ', () => {
    let routerSpy: SpyObject<Router>;
    beforeEach(() => {
      routerSpy = spectator.inject(Router);
    });
    it('should change document location href', () => {
      const routeUrl = 'newPath';
      const event = new NavigationEnd(1, '', routeUrl);
      (routerSpy.events as Subject<unknown>).next(event);
      expect(document.location.href).toBe('newPath');
    });
  });
```

But the result is
`Expected: "newPath" Received: "http://localhost/`

I always receive localhost. ¿How can I change localhost?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a test, `document.location` isn't used.

You need to rely on the `Location` instance:

```js
const location = TestBed.get(Location);
expect(location.path()).toEqual('/1');
```

An example of testing Router is here: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/route